# How can I select data from SQL server to gridview in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I select data to display in a gridview with button sorry guys I am really confused thx for help T>T

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
    string strConnString = null;
    string strSQL = null;

    strConnString = "Server=localhost;UID=sa;PASSWORD=1234;Database=Machining;Max Pool Size=400;Connect Timeout=600;";
    objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString;
    objConn.Open();

    //    int intNumRows = 0;
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ADMS_Machining = ";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    objConn.Close();
}
```

and `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: 1. Fetch Connection string from web.config since you have already added that. 2. You need to set the connection for `sda` 3. Remove `ExecuteNonQuery`, no need in case of dataAdapters 4. Consider wrapping your code inside `using`. Thus, Its "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ADMS_Machining ";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```